# The group of roots of unity is a reflection group

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, automorphism-group, roots-of-unity

Let $C(r)$ be the group of $r-$roots of unity. I read that $C(r)$ acts on $\mathbb C$ as a reflection group. Could you please explain how is that?

Here is my understanding of the action: $C(r)=<\alpha>$, for some primitive $r-$root of unity $\alpha\in \mathbb C$. The action is defined by the multiplication: $C(r)\times \mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C$, $(\alpha, z) \longmapsto \alpha z$.

The definitions I have in mind are the following: A reflection is a finite order automorphism $f\in GL(\mathbb C)$ such that $\ker(f-id)$ is a hyperplane of $\mathbb C$.

A reflection group is any subgroup of $GL(\mathbb C)$ generated by reflections.

Answer (score 1):

A *complex* reflection of $\mathbb C^n$ is an element $f\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$ of finite order such that $\ker(f-id)$ is of *complex* dimension $n-1$. Thus, a complex reflection of $\mathbb C$ is a root of unity distinct from $1$. $C(r)$ is generated by such an element. According to [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_reflection_group), $C(r)=G(r,1,1)$.

Comment: If we write the action as $f_\alpha:\mathbb C \longrightarrow \mathbb C; z\longmapsto \alpha z$ then $f_\alpha$  fixes only $z=0$ so how can we see $f_\alpha$ as a reflection?

Comment: Precisely! $\ker(f_\alpha-id)=\{0\}$ is of *complex* codimension $1$ in $\mathbb C$.